# Why would a smart switch not turn on if seemingly wired correctly?

Tags: electrical, lighting, garage

We have floodlights that I would like to put on a timer using a Geeni Tap smart switch. I killed the power, uninstalled the old switch. Gang box has 2 black wires, a white wire, and a bare copper wire.

1 black wire is from the romex, the other is outside/separate from the romex. I assume the separated black wire is the switch wire, because it was installed on a screw labelled "common" on the old switch.

Used the wire nuts included with the new switch to connect the leads accordingly:

black romex wire to line lead

white romex wire to neutral lead

black standalone wire to brown switch lead

The switch shows no signs of life after flipping the breaker back on.

I took the switch inside, and wired it in our kitchen to test it.
Kitchen gang box has 2 black wires, and 2 white wires taped together.

I took the 2 taped white wires, separated them, then put them in a wire nut together with the neutral lead from the switch. Connected the black wires (1 to switch lead, 1 to line lead), and the switch turned on and worked properly.

What exactly am I missing with installing this in the garage? The old switch worked just fine, I wire this new switch, and nothing. Take it indoors and wire it elsewhere and it works just fine.

The electricity in the garage seems to work fine still, as the interior light still works.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Was the white wire connected to the old switch?  A single black wire is usually not a good sign, someone did not follow code.  Neutral must be white, but often white is not neutral and used for another function.  To be safe you might be looking at checking/redoing the wiring.

Comment: @crip659 Yes all 3 main wires (white, both blacks) were connected to original switch. But you're saying that the black could be neutral?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Added some photos at the end of the post.

Comment: If connected to the switch then no neutral.  White is/was a hot or switched hot, also known as a switch loop.  To get neutral to the switch, you will need a three wire cable(plus ground) from the light.  Or you can get a smart switch which does not require a neutral.

Comment: @crip659 So what you're saying is that the 3 wires (white, black, separated black) are hot, hot, and on/off?

Comment: It looks very humid or wet in that area.  Don't expect a cheap smart switch to last very long. Where do the wires go?  Can you follow/trace them?  What is at the other end of that single black wire?

Answer (score 3):

##### STOP!

In the US wiring scheme (other places are similar, but colors and terminology vary a bit, but this is clearly US):

- Wires must either be in cables (usually non-metallic, NM, commonly referred to by the brand name Romex) or individual wires in conduit.
- Individual wires, with the exception of ground wires in certain situations, must *never* be exposed outside of an appliance or a junction box (switch box, receptacle box or a box literally used just as a place to connect things together). Individual wires need to be inside *conduit*, which groups wires together and provides varying amounts of protection (at a minimum, protection from human fingers, but with certain types protection from animals and shovels and other things).
- All wires must be grouped (so never an individual wire by itself) and connected in a way that currents are *balanced*. That generally means you will find wires (ignoring ground wires) in combinations of:

  - Hot (a.k.a., line) + switched hot (a.k.a., load)
  - Hot + neutral
  - Hot + switched hot + neutral
  - Switched hot + neutral
  - Hot + travelers (3-way switch circuits)
  - Switched hot + travelers
  - Neutral + travelers

There are probably a few other possibilities as well. But the basic idea is that you never have a wire by itself. (Exception: Old knob and tube where the wires are deliberately kept far apart, but that is obsolete and clearly not the case here.)

So before trying to figure out the switch, you need **fix the wires**. Meaning, at a minimum, find what other wire is supposed to be with the lonely black wire, and replace the separate wires with a *cable*.

One possibility, but it is only a guess, is that the single black wire is switched hot and the cable contains hot (black) and neutral (white). If that's the case, and if the single wire and the cable go to the same location, then the solution is to replace it with a /3 cable - black/red/white/ground. In that case, red is used as switched hot (not required, but by convention) and black (hot), white (neutral) and bare (ground) replace the existing /2 cable.

But there are some other possibilities. Impossible to tell without pictures of the other end of the black wire, the other end of the cable, the light fixture junction box and possibly some other things.

But before dealing with a fancy newfangled smart switch, you have to get the basics not only working but safe and code-compliant.

Comment: When you say things are to be balanced, is that why when I installed the switch in our kitchen, there were 2 white and 2 black? It's late and dark now, but you're saying there should be another wire to go with that lone black? I'm curious to go back out tomorrow morning and follow that wire and see if there is anything else now.

Comment: With *cables*, it is nearly always black+white or black+red+white. With individual wires *in conduit*, it can be almost anything but always 2 or more wires *together*. I have some hunches as to what is going on, but they are just hunches. You need to trace that black wire *and* the cable to see where things go.

Comment: Will do. Thank you for being so detailed and informative.